# ParaView get file path

Tags: vtk, paraview

I am opening some VTU files from Directory X and there are other output files in that directory (for example log.txt) that I want to open via a plugin. If I do a `os.getcwd()` I end up in ParaViews installation directory. What I want is the directory of the VTU files I loaded BEFORE applying the plugin... So basically the start Point of the Pipline.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to get the reader

`myreader = FindSource('MyReader')`

then get the file name via the FileName attribute

`myreader.FileName`